# Bit manipulation solution for majority element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

Source: https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/28601/java-solutions-sorting-hashmap-moore-voting-bit-manipulation/2

Q: Identify the element that appears most in an array.
I was able to solve it but was curious to look at others' solutions. So I came across the solution which uses bit-manipulation.

```
public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
    int[] bit = new int[32];
    for (int num: nums)
        for (int i=0; i<32; i++) 
            if ((num>>(31-i) & 1) == 1)
                bit[i]++;
    int ret=0;
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
        bit[i]=bit[i]>nums.length/2?1:0;
        ret += bit[i]*(1<<(31-i));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

When I replace the line

```
ret += bit[i]*(1<<(31-i));
```

with

```
ret += bit[i]*(1<<i);
```

I end up getting a negative number.

Consider the input array - [2, 5, 5, 5, 3], after the first for loop, bit[0] will contain 4, bit[1] = 2, bit[3] = 3 and all the other bits will be 0.

As per my understanding, the second for loop will result in the number whose bit positions 31 and 29 set to 1 (which is not same as 5).
I am clearly missing something in my understanding.

Can someone please explain how does this code work?
Thanks.

Comment: Before asking here, I recommend you step through the code in your IDE debugger to understand what happens at each step.

Comment: Why can't we do it with a `HashMap`? Wouldn't it be `n+n` complexity?

Comment: There are two places the expression `31 - i` appears in that code.  If you don't change _both_ of them, you're going to get weird behavior.

Comment: @sonnet yes, but this uses less space and although both algorithms are O(n) space and time, this would (guessing) be faster because it involves simpler operations.

Answer (score 6):

The algorithm first determines the frequency of each bit in the input array. If there is a number with a majority in the input (i.e. it makes up more than half of the input), then the frequency of all its set bits will be in the majority, and the frequency of all its unset bits will be in the minority.

The majority number can be recreated from the frequency table by masking together all the majority bits. This relies on there being a majority. If there is not guaranteed to be a majority a second pass to check the result is required.

```
public static int majorityElement4(int[] nums) {
    // Bit frequency table 
    int[] bit = new int[32];

    // Work out bit frequency
    for (int num : nums)
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)   // for each bit
            if ((num & 1 << i) != 0)   // is bit i set?
                bit[i]++;              // increment frequency

    // Recreate the majority number 
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)       // for each bit   
        if (bit[i] > nums.length / 2)  // is bit i in the majority?
            ret |= 1 << i;             // mask bit i into the result
    return ret;
}
```

As noted by @Louis, you needed to reverse the index in the frequency counter as well as the result calculation to make your simplification work.

Comment: What is the complexity of this solution? Is it O(N*M) Where N = number of elements and M = number of bits.